# why does openDJ's import-ldif complain about file permissions on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, updates, opendj

i'm using openDJ on windows 7, trying to run import-ldif and i'm getting the message below.
the files in that folder are NOT read-only.
what is the remedy for this?

the message i'm getting is this:
[31/???/2012:07:05:53 +0200] severity="SEVERE_WARNING" msgCount=12 msgID=8519808 message="An error occurred while setting file permissions for the backend database directory C:\Users\inor\OpenDJ\db\userRoot: org.opends.server.types.DirectoryException: One or more updates to the file permissions for
 C:\Users\inor\OpenDJ\db\userRoot failed, but at least one update was successful.  Some of the permissions for the file may have been altered"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message indicates that the server could not set the permissions to all the files in a consistent manner, while the OpenDJ server was creating the database files during the import.

This seems to indicate either the lack of rights for the user to perform those changes or that some files were not owned by the user. It is highly recommended to run OpenDJ on Windows as a user that has Administrator rights.

Kind regards,

Ludovic